# Datatable is not Showing data

Tags: javascript, json, datatables

im developing a datatable in ASPX page, the data comes from a asmx webservice, but I have some issues showing the Info in the table.

This is the HTML of my table:

```
 <table id="tablaNacional" class="table table-hover ">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Concepto</th>
                <th>CantidadVenta</th>
                <th>CantidadTMK</th>
                <th>PorcentajeTMK</th>
                <th>CantidadCompartidos</th>
                <th>PorcentajeCompartidos</th>
                <th>CantidadPresencial</th>
                <th>PorcentajePresencial</th>
                <th>Periodo</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="cuerpoDatosTabla">
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And this is mi datatable Js Code:

```
var table = $('#tablaNacional').DataTable({

            "sScrollY": "true",
            //'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers',
            //'iDisplayLength': 5,
            "select": true,
            "bPaginate": true,
            "bProcessing": true,
            //"bServerSide": false,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            url: DatosTabla,
       dataSrc:"d",
            columns: nColumns,
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
            ],

        "scrollX": "100%",
        "sDom": "<'row'<'col-md-6 'l><'col-md-6'Bf>>" +
        "<'row'<'col-md-6 '><'col-md-6'>>" +
        "<'row'<'col-md-12't>><'row'<'col-md-12'ip>>",
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar_MENU_",
            "sSearch": "Buscar",
            "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst": "Primero",
                "sLast": "Último",
                "sNext": "Siguiente",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior"
            },
        },
        "fnInitComplete": function (oSettings, json) {

            //$('#tblClases tbody tr:eq(0)').addClass('selected');

        }

    });
```

And this is my Json Data:

```
{"d":"[{\"Concepto\":\"Nacional\",\"CantidadVenta\":\"75096367.03\",\"CantidadTMK\":\"521320.50\",\"PorcentajeTMK\":\"0.69\",\"CantidadCompartidos\":\"1011596.05\",\"PorcentajeCompartidos\":\"1.35\",\"CantidadPresencial\":\"1961872.26\",\"PorcentajePresencial\":\"2.61\",\"Periodo\":\"201811\"}]"}
```

No errors in Developer chrome tools, just the table doesn't show data, only shows "No data available in table".

I think it's a little thing but I can't find the issue.

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Try read the documentation -> **https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax**, then delete your question ... :)

Comment: Nope, I can't get nothing. Thanks.

Comment: You do not see *any* difference between the use of  `ajax.url` and `ajax.dataSrc` in the documentation and how you do it above?

Comment: Ok, I found the response: ASMX or the webservice, send the response in string format, just parse that string  with JSON.parse(DatosTabla.d) and it works!!.

Comment: Great you got it to work! You should really use `ajax: { url: DatosTabla, dataSrc:"d" },` (assuming `DatosTabla` is a url / uri) JSON is *always* sent as string, it is expected and will be parsed by DataTables. But there is some peculiar thing about ASP (as far as I recall) where you need to set the `dataType` or something like that, dont know if that was the case here ..You could answer your own question and mark it as accepted, perhaps it will help future visitors. .

Comment: Some annotations ajax: { url: DatosTabla, dataSrc:"d" }, nope avoid the dataSrc, in my case url:DatosTabla was an string, this string comes from another function, but this string comes stringed or wathever that means, and I have to convert him to JSON object with parse method.

Comment: Then you could just use `data: DatosTabla.d` ...And obviously JSONfy the string first.  I guess you have found the best solution. Surprised if it works with `url: DatosTabla` ...